# HttpGet params not being sent

Tags: android, apache, http, http-get

I'm using apache.http on android and most of it works fine but when I try to do a get request with parameters, these are nor being sent. What am I doing wrong? Here's the code

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpUriRequest request = new HttpGet(uri);

HttpParams p = new BasicHttpParams();
p.setParameter("param", "value");
request.setParams(p);

request.setHeader("Accept", "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01");

HttpResponse response = null;

try {
    response = httpclient.execute(request);
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

On the server im getting only this with no params

```
GET /api/v1/activity/ HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to modify the URI, like so:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

String url = "http://example.com";
List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
params.add( new BasicNameValuePair( "param", "value" ) );
URI uri = new URI( url + "?" + URLEncodedUtils.format( params, "utf-8" );

HttpUriRequest request = new HttpGet(uri);

request.setHeader("Accept", "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01");

HttpResponse response = null;

try {
    response = httpclient.execute(request);
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: This works great and I'm using it now but according to everyone else the setParams method should do the trick. It's odd.

Comment: It seems like it should, but I've never seen an example that uses `setParams()`. Even Apache's official example uses `URIBuilder`'s `setParameter` method to build the params out in the URI.